# Kendo Tabstrip tab with close button

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-tabstrip

I have a kendo tabstrip with close button. The problem is that I can't get the button click event to close that tab.

```
 @(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
  .Name("test")
  .Items(tabstrip =>
  {
     tabstrip.Add().Text("")
     .Selected(true)
     .ContentHtmlAttributes(new { style = "overflow: auto;" })
     .Content("");
  })
  .SelectedIndex(0)
  )

<script>
  tab.append({
    text: "" + name + " <input type='button' id='ddddd'>X</input> ",
    contentUrl: content,
    encoded: false
    //imageUrl: "/Images/close.png" <span class='tabdelete k-button'><span class=' k-icon k-i-close' ></span></span>
   })

 $("#ddddd").click(function () {
    alert("done");
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Where's the code where you add the click event listener? There's not enough information to help you, I'm afraid...

Comment: where is the event handler

Comment: added handler for checking!...

Comment: edited my question, is this ok?

Comment: here i am appending tab from a button click, each tab need close button, help me plzzz

Comment: @AndreiV help me plz

Comment: Do you see the button (the `X`) on the tab? Where do you get the `content` variable from? What does it contain?

Comment: @AndreiV .button text correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
<input type='button' class="button" id='ddddd'>X</input>


   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
             //replace your selector if u need ID
              //$('body').on('click', '#buttonID', function () {
            $('body').on('click', '.button', function () {

                alert('ddsda');
            });
        });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your requirement look like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/palanikumar/8jf2wpng/)? http://jsfiddle.net/palanikumar/8jf2wpng/

```
$('.cls-btn').click(function()
{
    var index = $(this).parent().parent().index();
    var tabStrip = $('#tabstrip').getKendoTabStrip();
    tabStrip.remove(index);
    tabStrip.select(0);
});
```